# JPA merge of a @OneToOne entity relationship

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink

I have a `@OneToOne` relationship between two JPA entities, the following example is simplified and not the real entity names.

```
@Entity
public class Stock {

    @Id
    private Long id;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.Lazy, mappedBy = "stock", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private StockDetail detail;

}
```

And StockDetail

```
@Entity
public class StockDetail {

    @Id
    private Long id;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "STOCK_ID")
    private Stock stock;
}
```

In my example I need to search for stock by ID and then update the stock detail using `merge` eg.

```
Stock stock = em.find(Stock.class, 1L);
StockDetail detail = stock.getDetail();
// Do some updates to detail
detail = em.merge(detail);
```

At this point with the debugger I can see that the returned `detail` from the merge is the updated JPA entity. However I have an issue when I do the following again.

```
Stock stock = em.find(Stock.class, 1L);
StockDetail detail = stock.getDetail();
```

`detail` now seems to have the old state of the entity, I'm not sure what's wrong with the above

Comment: Are you using another entityManager for both operations?

Comment: Have you commited your changes after your merges?

Comment: after changes done to the detail try to mere on stock not detail object 'em.merge(stock);'. cascade mention in stock.

Comment: @NicoVanBelle actually yes there are two entitymangers, one for reading (non cached) one for updating (cached). Using JTA for both

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was actually a combination of @NicoVanBelle and @janith1024 comments.

1. There were two entitymanagers, a non-cached em used to do the find and a cached em used for doing the merge.
2. Once I made the non-cached em do the merge on the stock, it started working.

Comment: I din't notice the mention yesterday but yes that is what I was getting at. Good job finding it on your own!